# How to save media files under "http://example.com/custom_folder" for a specific page

Tags: uploads

I want to upload images in a specific folder like `http://example.com/custom_folder`.

Note: Not in `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/custom_folder/image1.jpg`

Comment: See this demo url for your expectation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35130833/how-to-upload-some-media-files-under-http-domain-name-folder-name-for-a-spec/35148358#35148358

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
add_filter('upload_dir', 'upload_image_specific_calback');
function upload_image_specific_calback( $param ){

    //$_GET['post'] which is your target post like 10 is post id.
    //After click update button.
    if(isset($_GET['post'])){
        if($_GET['post'] == 10){
            $param = array(
            'path' => get_home_path().'logos',
            'url' => home_url().'/logos',
            'subdir' => '',
            'basedir' => get_home_path(),
            'baseurl' => home_url(),
            'error' => false
            ); 
        }
    }

    //$_POST['post_id'] which is your target post like 10 is post id.
    //instant upload time before save
    if(isset($_POST['post_id'])){ 
        if($_POST['post_id'] == 10) {
            $param = array(
            'path' => get_home_path().'logos',
            'url' => home_url().'/logos',
            'subdir' => '',
            'basedir' => get_home_path(),
            'baseurl' => home_url(),
            'error' => false
            );
        }   
    }

    error_log("path={$param['path']}");  
    error_log("url={$param['url']}");
    error_log("subdir={$param['subdir']}");
    error_log("basedir={$param['basedir']}");
    error_log("baseurl={$param['baseurl']}");
    error_log("error={$param['error']}"); 
    return $param;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The filter you'd want to use is [`upload_dir`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/upload_dir). Check for the `post_id` key in the `$_REQUEST` super global array to be equal to the page ID you want to limit this for. Then change the uploads directory accordingly.

In code:

```
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'my_uploads_dir' );

function my_uploads_dir( $param ){

    // change this to the ID of your page
    $post_id = 135;

    // skips all uploads not associated with your page
    if ( empty( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) || $_REQUEST['post_id'] != $post_id ) {
        return $param;
    }

    // set the name of your custom dir relative to WP root
    $mydir = 'awesome';

    $param['path'] = $param['basedir'] = ABSPATH . $mydir;
    $param['url']  = $param['baseurl'] = site_url('/') . $mydir;

    // ignore date-based sorting
    $param['subdir'] = '';

    return $param;
}
```

Where `$mydir` corresponds to your custom directory in the WordPress install root.

Comment: Image uploaded as my requirement. But, when i click on publish or update button the image was dismissed.Could not publish or update with the image.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your wp-config.php file

`define( 'UPLOADS', 'custom_folder' );`

And make sure to add this code before that.

`require_once( ABSPATH.’wp-settings.php’ );`

For more information you can check here
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/change-default-wordpress-uploads-folder/

Thanks

Comment: Please see the title of question.